# Cannot post questions anymore on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, asking-questions

I'm trying to post a question on Stack Overflow but it's not working. After I click "Post your question", the page loads endlessly and the question never gets posted. If a developer/moderator could have a look at it that would be great!

Comment: Using what browser? Have you tried hard reloading the page (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?  Your browser, I mean.

Comment: Ok I see what the problem was. I'm in a library and their filter is blocking posting questions on StackOverflow (the filter messages takes like 5 minutes to appear so I thought it was something else). I've now used a proxy to post the question.

Comment: Wow; crazy that their filter blocks this. But not amazed - was at a uni for a geek-day a while ago - the network blocked both SSL and VPN. Like... really?